# How to find the library type (.so or .a) in C++/UNIX

Tags: c++, unix

Given a C++/UNIX library file (without extension), i need to determine the type of library whether it is a dynamic library (.so file) or a static library (.a file) based on its content (say grepping the content against a keyword)

How do i do it in UNIX command line ?

Comment: `file <library name>` is not working?

Comment: My initial reaction as well. So, write up an answer, Aviator!

Comment: @DigitalRoss: Thanks. Have put it as an answer.

Comment: Good question - I will be needing this in the next few days!

Comment: Not a good question. This is vaguely programming related, and I believe it is better suited to Super User than Stack Overflow, strictly speaking.

Answer (score 5):

Try`file <library name>`. It should display`shared` or `dynamically linked` among its output if the file is a dynamically loadable module.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the reply. Your answer is perfectly fine. But i wanted to know how to proceed with the approach of 'grep'ping the library content for some keyword and determine the library type (if that's possible).

Comment: Why do you want to grep instead of use the file command?  The file command basically does this and has the magic numbers and other characteristics for hundreds of different file types in its database.  Whenever possible, let someone else maintain things like this for you.

Comment: @Arvind: Like Omnifarious asked, why do you need to `grep` and go for complex way when you have a simple `file` command :). Is there any specific reason that you are not wanting `file`?

Answer (score 1):

Try `file -L <library name> | grep shared` if this produces any output, the file is dynamically linked. Alternately you could do `ldd <library name> | grep 'not a dynamic executable'` which produces output if it's static. Hope this answers your question, I would have added a comment to Aviator's answer, but I cannot comment (yet).

The `-L` option to file forces files to dereference symlinks, which is not the default behavior if POSIXLY_CORRECT is not defined (as it is the case on my system).

Script example:

```
if [ -z "$(file -L  | grep shared)" ]; then
    echo "not a dynamic lib";
else
    echo "dynamic lib";
```